# Where can I go to get good reference images for modelling characters?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Im still kind of new to blender, but I am struggling to find any good reference images / characters online to help me practice retopo and sculpting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.de/search/pins/?rs=ac&len=2&q=character%20reference&eq=character%20refer&etslf=7441&term_meta[]=character%7Cautocomplete%7C0&term_meta[]=reference%7Cautocomplete%7C0) account.

Comment: pinterest is a garbage generator, there really are better places, you just need to do a google search with the right keywords, IMAGE, blueprint, reference, character sheet, depending on what you want to model or are looking for